# "Historical quote data is unavailable for the specified date range" for Yahoo finance when querying stock history

Tags: yahoo-finance

I've got a very strange problem when query stock history prices via yahoo finance,

I cannot query google stock prices from Jan-04-2010 to Apr-19-2013, i.e.

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG&a=00&b=04&c=2010&d=03&e=19&f=2013&g=d

got a error: "Historical quote data is unavailable for the specified date range."
```

but I can query prices from  Jan-04-2010 to Apr-19-2014, i.e.

```
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG&a=02&b=27&c=2011&d=03&e=19&f=2014&g=d
```

Anyone know what's wrong with my first query?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Google symbol has been changed to Googl try this it works for me:
http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOGl&a=00&b=04&c=2010&d=03&e=19&f=2013&g=d

Comment: wrong, both exist. GOOG are class C shares and GOOGL are class A shares